# expected type "..." defined at ....... error in Ada

Tags: ada

I have such a Karatsuba algorithm implementation I have written in ADA.

```
   procedure Karatsuba (Factor_1, Factor_2 : in Number; Product : out Number) is
      m : Integer;
      m2 : Integer;
      low1 : Number := (0,1);
      high1 : Number := (0,1);
      low2 : Number := (0,1);
      high2 : Number := (0,1);
      z0 : Index;
      z1 : Index;
      z2 : Index;
      x : Integer;
      y : Integer;
      hc1 : Index;
      hc2 : Index;
   begin
      low1 := (others => 0);
      high1 := (others => 0);
      low2 := (others => 0);
      high2 := (others => 0);  
      if Factor_1'Length = 1 or Factor_2'Length = 1 then
         Standard(Factor_1, Factor_2,Product);
      end if;
      -- calculates the size of the numbers
      m := Integer'Max(Factor_1'Length, Factor_2'Length);
      m2 := m / 2;
      -- split the digit sequences about the middle
      for Factor_1_Index in Factor_1'Range loop
         x := x + 1;
         if x <= m2 then
            low1(Factor_1_Index) := Factor_1(Factor_1_Index);
         else
            high1(hc1) := Factor_1(Factor_1_Index);
            hc1 := hc1 + 1;
         end if;
      end loop;
      for Factor_2_Index in Factor_2'Range loop
         y := y + 1;
         if y <= m2 then
            low2(Factor_2_Index) := Factor_2(Factor_2_Index);
         else
            high2(hc2) := Factor_2(Factor_2_Index);
            hc2 := hc2 + 1;
         end if;
      end loop;
      -- 3 calls made to numbers approximately half the size
      z0 := Karatsuba(low1, low2, Product);
      z1 := Karatsuba((low1 + high1), (low2 + high2), Product);
      z2 := Karatsuba(high1, high2, Product);
      Product := (z2*10**(2*m2))+((z1-z2-z0)*10**(m2))+(z0);
   end Karatsuba;
```

On the last 4 lines before "end Karatsuba" line, I get the error "expected type 'Index' defined at ...". The errors I'm receiving are, respectively,

```
expected type "Index" defined at ....
found package or procedure name
there is no applicable operator "+" for type "Number" defined at ......
```

This is another class that I have assigned some variables:

```
package ITI8590.Natural_Number_Multiplication is

   type Digit  is range 0 .. 1;
   type Index  is new Positive;
   type Number is array (Index range <>) of Digit;

   for Digit'Size use 1;

   procedure Standard(Factor_1, Factor_2 : in Number; Product : out Number);
   procedure Karatsuba(Factor_1, Factor_2 : in Number; Product : out Number);

end ITI8590.Natural_Number_Multiplication;
```

Now why I get this error? I couldn't solve it, and I'm stuck in it. Could you help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Surely you got more than just that one error message. Please copy-and-paste the *entire* error message into the question. `Karatsuba` is a procedure; it doesn't return a value. You're trying to assign its return value to `z0`, `z1`, and `z2`. (BTW, the name of the language is Ada, not ADA. It's not an acronym; it's names after a person.)

Comment: Okay Keith, I'm putting.

Comment: The error message `there is no applicable operator "+" for type "Number"` probably means that there is no operator `"+"` for the type `"Number"`.  Which there isn't.  `Number` is an array.  Ada does not automatically define numeric operators for arrays that operate on corresponding elements.  You can write one yourself, though.

Comment: @ajb: I’m not sure what the format of `Number` actually corresponds to, but I suspect it’s a representation of binary. In which case the operators are going to be more than ‘operating on corresponding elements’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Karatsuba` is a procedure, so at the end instead of

```
  z0 := Karatsuba(low1, low2, Product);
  z1 := Karatsuba((low1 + high1), (low2 + high2), Product);
  z2 := Karatsuba(high1, high2, Product);
```

it should probably read

```
  Karatsuba(low1, low2, z0);
  Karatsuba((low1 + high1), (low2 + high2), z1);
  Karatsuba(high1, high2, z2);
```

which requires you to declare `z0`, `z1`, `z2` as `Number` rather than `Index`. Note, `Product` is an `out` parameter to the procedure, so all your code achieved was to overwrite it twice with intermediate results (3 times, counting the call to `Standard` above).

But then you have a problem: the compiler says

```
yusuf.ada:25:12: unconstrained subtype not allowed (need initialization)
yusuf.ada:25:12: provide initial value or explicit array bounds
```

which is calling for something related to the way you have declared `low1` etc:

```
  low1 : Number := (0,1);
  high1 : Number := (0,1);
  low2 : Number := (0,1);
  high2 : Number := (0,1);
```

The trouble with this approach is that you’ve now constrained the bounds of the variables: `low1` is fixed to have 2 elements (set to values that you then overwrite), and can’t be expanded. I don’t know how the algorithm is supposed to work, but this seems unlikely to be right; for a start, what happens if the inputs have more than 2 digits?

One approach that might work is to use the number of digits in the input parameters:

```
Max_Digits : constant Positive := Factor_1’Length + Factor_2’length;
pragma Assert (Product’Length >= Max_Digits, “possible overflow”);
low1 : Number (1 .. Max_Digits) := (others => 0);
```

etc.

And, as ajb has commented, you’ll need to define operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `**` between `Number`s and `Integers` as needed, particularly in the expression `(z2*10**(2*m2))+((z1-z2-z0)*10**(m2))+(z0)` in the last line of the procedure.